# Change push notification icon (FCM) in Xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin

I am trying to do Push Notifications with Xamarin.Forms (Android) and FCM from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w2q2D6mR7g&list=PLfbOp004UaYX5B2pKKp5j7QPniyLMPkSO) , [code](https://github.com/jfversluis/XFFCMPushNotificationsSample)

Everything seems fine. However I am trying to change the notification icon. This is not in the tutorial.

I added this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

I created icons `ic_notification.png` and added folders:

```
Resources/drawable-mdpi/ (24x24)
Resources/drawable-hdpi/ (36x36)
Resources/drawable-xhdpi/ (48x48)
Resources/drawable-xxhdpi/ (72x72)
Resources/drawable-xxxhdpi/ (96x96)
```

However it still doesn't work. How can I change ico notification (FCM)? Thanks for the solutions!

[image]

[image]

**Update**
In Project Android. I created Application.cs

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            //Change for your default notification channel id here
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannelVenus";

            //Change for your default notification channel name here
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelImportance = NotificationImportance.Max;
        }

        //If debug you should reset the token each time.
   #if DEBUG
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
   #else
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
   #endif

        //Handle notification when app is closed here
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {
        };
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

I add in OnCreate:

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
   ....
   CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("all");
   CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += Current_OnTokenRefresh;
}

private void Current_OnTokenRefresh(object source, FirebasePushNotificationTokenEventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Token: {e.Token}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From document [Add a custom default notification icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#add-a-custom-default-notification-icon), we could find that

> If a custom default icon is not configured in AndroidManifest.xml and
> no icon is set in the notification payload, Android uses the
> application icon as the notification icon (as seen in the notification
> icon screenshot above).

So you can recheck if you have set the icon you mentioned in your Notification.

For example:

```
            notification.SetContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent)
                     .SetContentTitle(message.GetNotification().Title)
                     .SetContentText(message.GetNotification().Body)
                     .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, 
                      Resource.Drawable.water))
                     .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.water)
                     .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
                     .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
                     .SetColor(0x9c6114)
                     .SetAutoCancel(true)
                     .SetOngoing(true);


            manager.Notify(id, notification.Build());
```

Comment: If I have set `<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />`  in `AndroidManifest.xml`. But it doesn't seem to work. So do I need to set: `notification.SetContentIntent(...)`? I also uploaded `ic_notification.png` to the `drawable` folder

Comment: Could you please post the model in your app which implements `FirebaseMessagingService` here?

Comment: Yes, I have updated in the Update section above. You can consider it

Answer (score 0):

Try to set transparent icon:

```
PushNotificationManager.IconResource = Resource.Drawable.app_icon_transparent;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).